How can I call a transformation where only the $z$-axis is modified by a function in each point?
What is called a transformation that maps $z \rightarrow |f(z)|\, z$, while the other axis stays the same? Is it a conformal transformation?

In general, a map is conformal if the Jacobian is some positive scalar times an orthonormal matrix, so that it locally preserves angles between curves. Your suggested map is
$$\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y'\\ z'\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & |f(z)| \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}$$
The Jacobian of your transformation is
$$ J =\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial x'}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial x'}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial y'}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial y'}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial y'}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial z'}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial z'}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial z'}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&f'(z)\frac{f(z)}{|f(z)|}\end{pmatrix}$$
which cannot be factored into a positive scalar times a rotation matrix except in the trivial case of $f'(z)\frac{f(z)}{|f(z)|}=1$

Thanks, I see. But is there any common definition of a map of that kind?

There might be, but I have never heard of it.
